# Eight Queens Java exception error

Tags: java

Im trying to make a program to solve the eight Queens problem but i keep getting and exception error every time i run the code this is what i have. im a little confused on what to do. any help to the direction will be greatly appreciated.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1        at
>   Queens.isUnderAttack(Queens.java:132)         at
>   Queens.placeQueens(Queens.java:78)        at
>   Queens.main(Queens.java:155)

```
public class Queens
{
    //squares per row or column
    public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

    //used to indicate an empty square 
    public static final int EMPTY = 0;

    //used to indicate square contains a queen
    public static final int QUEEN = 1;

    private int board[][]; //chess board

    public Queens()
    {
        //constructor: Creates an empty square board.
        board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];

    }


    //clears the board
    //Precondition: None
    //Postcondition: Sets all squares to EMPTY
    public void clearBoard()
    {
        //loops through the rows
        for(int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
        {
            //loops through the columns
            for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
            {
                board[row][column] = EMPTY;
            }
        }   
    }


    //Displays the board 
    //precondition: None
    //postcondition: Board is written to standard output; 
    //zero is an EMPTY square, one is a square containing a queen (QUEEN).
    public void displayBoard()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
        {
            System.out.println("");

            for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
            {
                System.out.print(board[row][column] + " ");
            }
        }
    }



    //Places queens in columns of the board beginning at the column specified.
    //Precondition: Queens are placed correctly in columns 1 through column-1.
    //Postcondition: If a solution is found, each column of the board contains one queen and
    //method returns true; otherwise, returns false (no solution exists for a queen anywhere in column specified).
    public boolean placeQueens(int column)
    {
        if(column >= BOARD_SIZE)
        {
            return true; //base case
        }
        else
        {
            boolean queenPlaced = false;
            int row = 1; // number of square in column

            while( !queenPlaced && (row < BOARD_SIZE))
            {
                //if square can be attacked
                **if (!isUnderAttack(row, column))**
                {
                    setQueen(row, column); //consider next square in column
                    queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
                    //if no queen is possible in next column,
                    if(!queenPlaced)
                    {
                        //backtrack: remover queen placed earlier
                        //and try next square in column
                        removeQueen(row, column);
                        //++row;
                    }
                }
                row++;
            }
            return queenPlaced;
        }

    }



    //Sets a queen at square indicated by row and column
    //Precondition: None
    //Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a given row and column to Queen.
    private void setQueen(int row, int column)
    {
        board[row][column] = QUEEN; 
    }



    //removes a queen at square indicated by row and column
    //Precondition: None
    //Postcondition: Sets the square on the board in a given row and column to EMPTY.
    private void removeQueen(int row, int column)
    {
        board[row][column] = EMPTY;
    }


    //Determines whether the square on the board at a given row and column is
    //under attack by any queens in the columns 1 through column-1.
    //Precondition: Each column between 1 and column-1 has a queen paced in a square at
    //a specific row. None of these queens can be attacked by any other queen.
    //Postcondition: If the designated square is under attack, returns true: otherwise return false.
    private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column)
    {


            for (int y=0; y<BOARD_SIZE; y++)
            {
                if (board[row][y] == QUEEN ||    // possible horizontal attack
                        board[row-column+y][y] == QUEEN ||   // diagonal NW
                        **board[row+column-y][y] == QUEEN)     // diagonal SW**
                        return true;
            }

        return false;
    }



    private int index(int number)
    {
        //Returns the array index that corresponds to a row or column number.
        //Precondition: 1 <= number <= BOARD_SIZE.
        //Postcondition: Returns adjusted index value

        return number -1 ;
    }


    //main to test program
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Queens Q = new Queens();
        **if(Q.placeQueens(0))**
        {
            System.out.println(Q);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Possible");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: please point out line 132, 78 and 155

Comment: i added the bold(**) tags to them...please look at the code above again

Comment: You need to rework your diagonal checks. When `row == 1` and `column == 0`, `row-column+y == 1+y` goes from 1 to `1+BOARD_SIZE=9` which exceeds the array's size. Similarly, `row+column-y == 1-y` goes from 1 to `1-BOARD_SIZE=-7` which goes below zero (the lowest possible index). Also, I think you want to start placing queens from `row = 0`, in which case you still go out of bounds.

Comment: `queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);` has the opportunity to go outside the width of the board when row = 7.

Comment: @scrappedcola Incorrect, the OP checks for that at the start of `placeQueens` with `if(column >= BOARD_SIZE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE; y++)
    {
        if (board[row][y] == QUEEN)
            return true; // possible horizontal attack

        int x1 = row - column + y;
        if (0 <= x1 && x1 < BOARD_SIZE && board[x1][y] == QUEEN)
            return true; // diagonal NW

        int x2 = row + column - y;
        if (0 <= x2 && x2 < BOARD_SIZE && board[x2][y] == QUEEN)
            return true; // diagonal SW
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your loop in 'isUnderAttack()', this is not good:

```
board[row-column+y][y]
board[row+column-y][y]
```

As 'y' goes from '0' to 'board size', it will mean indexes out of the bounds of your array (unless row and column is both 0) - as the error message clearly stated.

The loop should be corrected with the appropriate indexes, or by adding conditions to check that the indexing is in bounds:

```
int rowIndex = row-column+y;
if(rowIndex>=0 && rowIndex<BOARD_SIZE) {
      if(board[row-column+y][y] == QUEEN) {
            return true;
      }
}
```

And of course the same for the other diagonal...

<sub>Damn, it is slow to type code on an android phone, even with a qwerty...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The value of either of these is going below zero

```
row-column+y
row+column-y
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the Scenarios which is causing the error
Consider this  case,board[row+column-y][y] == QUEEN
assume row=1,column=0 and y is 4 ,the index become -ve which is causing the error